# How to create CQ5 Workflow that kicks in while importing assets

Tags: aem

I am new to CQ5 and am wondering if there is a way to add a workflow to the DAM such a way that it kicks in when the users import file(s).

The workflow needs to do the following:

- Call an External API over HTTP (REST) providing the file or the location of the file
- The external service will perform some operations on the file and save the file
- The service will respond back with the newly saved file or the location of the saved file
- Workflow continues on with whatever else CQ5 does when importing files.

I came across the DAM Update Asset workflow where workflows can be dragged and dropped. I believe for my purpose, I will have to create a custom workflow?

I am new to CQ5 but now Java. I would love some guidance on how should I go about creating this custom workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 solutions here:

**1. Modify the DAM Update Asset workflow**

You may add a new step to the workflow you've mentioned. I suggest adding new `Process step` between *Metadata extraction* and *Thumbnail creation*, so you'll have all metadata, but still can modify the asset before creating thumbnails (assuming it's an image). Process step invokes a configured OSGi service implementing the [`WorkflowProcess`](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/workflow/exec/WorkflowProcess.html). More info in the [official docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html#Developing%20Process%20Step%20Implementations).

**2. Create a new workflow**

Implement WorkflowProcess as above, rather than adding `Process step` to the existing workflow, create a new one. The Launcher tab in the workflow console allows you to bind the created workflow to the event raised after uploading new asset.

**3. Create an event handler**

You don't have to use workflow at all. Create a new OSGi [event handler](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/how-to-manage-events-in-sling.html) and bind it to the [`DamEvent`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/DamEvent.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am leaning towards option one. The external service will be adding metadata to the asset so the process step I add will need to be before _Metadata extraction_ so that the metadata added by the external service can be read by CQ. Does that complicate matters for solution 1 you proposed? Also I'm new to CQ...can you guide me on how to access the asset or location of the asset in my workflow?

Comment: I was looking for a Workflow process step tutorial and came across this: http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/WorkflowPrecessStep.html I'm following that but just wanted to ask if you know of another better resource.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-aem-workflow-steps.html) seems to be more up-to-date.